# Add dynamic IP address to the "Authorised javascript origins" list in Google Cloud so that I can integrate Google sign-in into my web app?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, dynamic-ip

I have a web app that I want to integrate Google sign-in into.

I have created a client ID and added the client ID to the web app.

However, I am unable to add my dynamic IP address to the "Authorised javascript origins" list in Google Cloud. I have tried adding the IP address to the list, but it is not accepted.

I have also tried adding the IP address to the list using a wildcard, but this is not accepted either.

[Javascript authorised origins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o6NL.png)

How can I add a dynamic IP address to the "Authorised javascript origins" list in Google Cloud so that I can integrate Google sign-in into my web app?